# How to make Form Control to take blank field but no all white space charcaters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to validate a field in reactive form where the field can be blank as it is not a required field but it should not take all characters as white space. I have created a customer validators for this as follows:

**Custom-validator.ts**

```
export function whiteSpaceValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    const check = control.value.trim();
    return check === '' ? { 'whiteSpaceCheck': { value: control.value } } : null;
}
```

But what I noticed when the field is blank means no value is present this is getting triggered which I don't want actually.

Any solution for this except iterating each character in string and checking if it is equal to space or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if check is empty AND if check is not equal to the original value. This way if it is empty and not equal to the original, than trim removed ALL of the whitespace.

```
export function whiteSpaceValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    const check = control.value.trim();
    return check === '' && check != control.value? { 'whiteSpaceCheck': { value: control.value } } : null;
}
```